# Flutter drawImage in 'package:image/image.dart throws Error

Tags: flutter

This is the line casing the error. I have two images, nImage and nSign, tested and printed. All I want is to draw image onto other one.

```
   print("nImage width${nImage.width} heigth ${nImage.height}");
   print("nSign width${nSign.width} heigth ${nSign.height}");
   Image savedImage =  drawImage(
        nImage, //dst
        nSign, //src
        dstX: 0,
        dstY: 0,
        srcX: 0,
        srcY: 0,
      );
```

console

```
I/flutter (15153): nImage width4608 heigth 3456
I/flutter (15153): nSign width344 heigth 643
I/flutter (15153): RangeError (index): Index out of range: index should be 
less than 21314: 21314
```

What should I do to get drawImage result?
 all i need to draw signature on image in specific place 
full example to  reproduce error
https://github.com/mhmoudsabry/Flutter_drawImage_FullExample_Error

Comment: Hi, please, provide a complete working code that can replicate the error

Comment: Readers will need to see how `nImage` and `nSign` are defined. I wonder if one image is being drawn on another such that the start point is outside of the drawable area, or maybe the whole image needs to fit onto the target in order for there not to be an error.

Comment: " maybe the whole image needs to fit onto the target in order for there not to be an error" How ??

Comment: https://github.com/mhmoudsabry/Flutter_drawImage_FullExample_Error